# How Can I Make This 2-Page PHP Login Script Remember User Input On Page 2

Tags: php

I'm struggling to create a two-paged form using $_SESSION. What I want to achieve is the first page (page1.php) requires the user to enter his/her email address. And the second page (page2.php) requires the user to enter his/her password.

When the user submits page1.php, it takes you to page2.php, where the email address submitted will be printed. But unfortunately, the email address is not printed, as intended.

Please, note I've tried to adopt related resolved threads, but I'm still missing something.

```html
<?php
session_start();
?>
<?php error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); ?>
<!doctype html>
<html><head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>2 Step Login - Page 1</title>
<link href="page1.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

<div id="formwrap">
<div id="form_inner">
    <div id="logo">
      <img src="" alt="logo">
    </div>
    <div id="email">
      
    </div>
  <div id="pwd">
      Sign in
  </div>
  <div id="form">
    <form action="page2.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form">
    
<?php

 //On page 1
    $_SESSION['username'] = $var_value;
?>
      <input id="username" name="username" type="text" placeholder="Email" autofocus required>
      
    
    <div id="forgot">No Yet A Member, Register Here</a></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="username" value="var_value">
    <input id="send" name="submit" type="submit" value="Next">
    </form>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<?php
session_start();
?>
<?php error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); ?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>2 Step Login - Page 2</title>
<link href="page2.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

<div id="formwrap">
<div id="form_inner">
    <div id="logo">
      <img src="" alt="logo">
    </div>
    <div id="email">
<?php
 //On age 2
    $var_value = $_SESSION['username'];
 echo $_SESSION['username'];
?>
    </div>
  <div id="pwd">
      Enter password
  </div>
  <div id="form">
    <form action="login.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form">
      <input id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" autofocus>
      <div id="chkbx">
<div id="inptch">
  <input id="keep_signed_in" name="keep_signed_in" type="checkbox" value="">
</div>
Keep me signed in</div>
    
    <div id="forgot">I Forgot My Password</div>
    <div id="different_account">Not A Member, Register Here</div>
    <input type="hidden" name="username" value="var_value">
    <input type="hidden" name="password" value="var_value">
    <input id="send" name="submit" type="submit" value="Sign in">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're in PHP: just generate it into whatever second, third, etc. page your PHP script makes? You're on the right track but where's the code that actually _saves_ the email address into the session? Because unless you first put it there, it's not going to be available for that session in subsequent runs.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, I don't know how to save the email into the session. That's why I'm here for a pointer.

Comment: Session is just a variable, you can assign it like any other variable. There will be examples available online already I'm quite sure

Comment: $_SESSION is empty, until you put things in it, so the logical first step is "if you want to put something in it, have a user send you that data". E.g. they post a form with their username/email and password, you process that post and put the username/email in $_SESSION. Google for `using sessions in PHP` and you will find _many_ tutorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code, it looks like you've skipped the step from using the POST value from the first form before getting to the second.

After a form is submitted, in PHP a $_POST variable contains the values of what was in the form from the keys of the name in the form.

For example `<input name="myinput">` in a form set to POST will result in `$_POST['myinput']` containing the value from the submit you submit.

The simple way to achieve what you want would be to just post the value from `page1.php` to `page2.php`, and then it looks like you handle the login on a `login.php`. For example:

`page1.php`

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['invalidEmail'])) {
        echo "Error: Invalid email address entered.";
    }
?>
<form action="page2.php" method="post">
    <input type="email" type="email" />
    <input type="submit" value="Continue" />
</form>
```

`page2.php`

```
<?php
    $email = htmlentities($_POST['email']);
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        // the email address is not valid, redirect them back to page1.php
        header('Location: page1.php?invalidEmail=true');
    }
?>
<form action="login.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?=$email?>" />
    <input type="password" type="password" />
    <input type="submit" value="Continue" />
</form>
```

`login.php`

```
<?php
    session_start(); // before any HTML is echoed
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // ..do whatever you need todo to validate the email and password
    // now you can use something like $_SESSION['loggedin'] = $email which will persist across any pages 
    // you can check `if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']))` to check if they're signed in
    // if the validation fails, redirect them back to page1.php with another error
?>
```

This way you're not using `$_SESSION` between pages and a user must go through from entering their email on page 1, to then adding their password on page 2 and finally validating on the `login.php` file.

The above will get the basics right for you and hopefully allow you to get where you need to go. There are a few extra things you will want to consider (though without having a firm understanding of the above, the rest won't work..)

1. Validation between pages - from page1 (collecting email) to page2, I've added a line to collect and validate an email address format. You might want to do some extra validation to see if it exists in your records before asking for a password.
2. Input sanitization - you'll notice I've used `htmlentities` around the `$_POST['email']` - this is to prevent users from injecting extra code on page2
3. From page2.php, if you visit it directly you're always redirected to page1.php because it requires an email address to be posted to it. You may want to consider what should happen here.
4. The flow here also means you can't skip between pages and must go through page1 => page2 => login. This is almost to be expected, but setting `$_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email']` would allow you to persist the entered data between pages.

Comment: Your time and pointer are mush appreciated. I'll apply what you suggested and get back. Thanks one again.